# How to find DLL's loaded into a process and it's location, etc

Tags: dll, process

I've used Process Explorer, but I'm forgetting of another utility that lets you see where a process is loaded from (image file), and it's dll's in memory and where they got loaded from.

Process Explorer for me is only working for managed assemblies.

Anything that does native as well?

Answer (score 9):

Process Explorer should show you both native and managed modules.  Trying running it elevated.

Otherwise, there are a few ways:

1. Use tlist.exe, part of the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) package (e.g. `tlist cmd.exe`)
2. Attach the VS debugger and look in the modules window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) or attach WinDbg and use the `lm` command
3. Use [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489(VS.85).aspx), [`Module32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684218(VS.85).aspx), and [`Module32Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684221(VS.85).aspx) to roll your own solution :)

Answer (score 3):

There's also an open-source tool "[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)".

It's an advanced task manager.
Select any process, hit "Enter", choose "Modules" tab.

Comment: Another way is to right-click> properties > modules

Answer (score 0):

[ListDLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls) from Windows Sysinternals is a command line tool that does what you are looking for:

`Listdlls.exe notepad.exe` or `Listdlls.exe 11524` give:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
notepad.exe pid: 11524
Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"

Base                Size      Path
0x00000000bfae0000  0x38000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe
0x00000000aee10000  0x1f5000  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00000000ad4c0000  0xbd000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00000000ac9a0000  0x2c8000  C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
<snip>
0x0000000093580000  0xf9000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll
0x00000000aebc0000  0x6b000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00000000aaf00000  0x33000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
```

`Listdlls.exe -d textinputframework.dll` give:

```
<snip>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
notepad.exe pid: 11524
Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"

Base                Size      Path
0x0000000093580000  0xf9000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll
```

`Listdlls.exe` (without parameters) outputs the dlls of all running processes.