# DirectX3D 11 enumerating devices

Tags: visual-c++, directx, directx-11

I would like to write a program that lists all DirectX3D applications running on a Windows System and displaying the resources they use. I know how to enumerate the adapters using the IDXGIFactory interface and the adapter outputs via the IDXGIAdapter interface. I also know how to find out the adapter used by an ID3D11Device using QueryInterface and GetParent. Though, I need the reverse: an enumeration of ID3D11Device which operate on a given adapter. You need to specify an IDXGIAdapter creating an ID3D11Device via D3D11CreateDevice. So there must be a connection. Are there any ideas how to get such an enumeration?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching processes that have loaded directx dll. [finding loaded dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454281/how-to-find-dlls-loaded-into-a-process-and-its-location-etc)

OR

You can place a global hook on D3D11CreateDevice and whenever some application calls it enlist that application.

Comment: I placed the question here because I hoped beeing able to avoid hooking. In the meantime I see that my doubts concerning hooking were causeless. I tried your second proposal and it works quite well. Thanks for the hint.