# ASM - Windows - Start Process

Tags: windows, assembly, createprocess

I would like to start a process with pure asm (inline c++ asm -> no masm). The problem is that I don't know how to get the adress of the system() function. Everytime I recompile the program, the adress changes. So is there any way to start a process? I've found a solution for linux. But there the execve function just gets disassembled and inlined:

```
0x80002bc <__execve>:   pushl  %ebp
0x80002bd <__execve+1>: movl   %esp,%ebp
0x80002bf <__execve+3>: pushl  %ebx
0x80002c0 <__execve+4>: movl   $0xb,%eax
0x80002c5 <__execve+9>: movl   0x8(%ebp),%ebx
0x80002c8 <__execve+12>:        movl   0xc(%ebp),%ecx
0x80002cb <__execve+15>:        movl   0x10(%ebp),%edx
0x80002ce <__execve+18>:        int    $0x80
0x80002d0 <__execve+20>:        movl   %eax,%edx
0x80002d2 <__execve+22>:        testl  %edx,%edx
0x80002d4 <__execve+24>:        jnl    0x80002e6 <__execve+42>
0x80002d6 <__execve+26>:        negl   %edx
0x80002d8 <__execve+28>:        pushl  %edx
0x80002d9 <__execve+29>:        call   0x8001a34 <__normal_errno_location>
0x80002de <__execve+34>:        popl   %edx
0x80002df <__execve+35>:        movl   %edx,(%eax)
0x80002e1 <__execve+37>:        movl   $0xffffffff,%eax
0x80002e6 <__execve+42>:        popl   %ebx
0x80002e7 <__execve+43>:        movl   %ebp,%esp
0x80002e9 <__execve+45>:        popl   %ebp
0x80002ea <__execve+46>:        ret
0x80002eb <__execve+47>:        nop
```

see: http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

But the CreateProcess- and the system-function in windows is much more complicated. So is there a possibility to create a process with raw assembler code. I have to do do the same bufferoverrun attack as descriped [here](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) for school. But I don't get it how to get the the adress of the function to start a process.

Comment: Windows has security measures to stop you doing this.  A discussion of the techniques that might be used for bypassing these measures would be too long for a Stack Overflow question.  Voting to close.

Comment: Well. I've actualy got it working. But I had to use the VirtualAlloc function to make the code executable.

Comment: @florian-r But ... but ... how did you do it?

Comment: What exactly do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that the Windows OS internally uses a mechanism similar to "int 0x80" in Linux (it was "int 0x2E" in Windows NT 4.x) however this mechanism is not official and therefore may change from version to version.

Therefore Windows programs must officially use the code from the .DLL files that come with the operating system. If you write an .EXE file that does not call any .DLL file (I tried that!) Windows sees that no .DLL is called and therefore assumes that the program simply does nothing and does not even load the .EXE file.

This means you'll have to call functions defined in .DLL files under Windows.

You can do this the simple way:

```
call _system
```

(Note that under Windows C functions have a trailing underscore when used in assembler!)

In this case the linker will create a wrapper (here in AT&T syntax):

```
_system:
    jmp *__imp__system
```

Or you can call the DLL directly (in AT&T syntax again):

```
call *__imp__system
```

You have to link against the .DLL files (e.g. msvcrt.dll for "_system").

-- EDIT --

If you want to inject code into a process you may find the answers to the following question useful:

[How to find DLL's loaded into a process and it's location, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454281/how-to-find-dlls-loaded-into-a-process-and-its-location-etc)

"msvcrt.dll" is not neccessarily used by every process however "kernel32.dll" should be used by nearly all processes.

"kernel32.dll" contains "LoadLibraryA" so you can load "msvcrt.dll" or you may use "CreateProcessA" (from kernel32.dll) directly.

The offset from the start of the DLL file to the entry point of a function is always the same so you can calculate:

```
address_of_function_in_debugged_process = 
    address_of_function_in_debugger -
    DLL_address_in_debugger + /* should be equal to the DLL HINSTANCE */
    DLL_address_in_debugged_process
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it does not really solve my problem. Since the assembly code gets injected into a running process "call _system" won't work. As far as I can see, "call _system" gets translated into something like "call [adressofsystem]". But the adress will change from time to time, so I can't use something like that. I really would need to use the interupt... but I can't find any information about that. Is that still supported in windows 8?